# Angular Material table set/disable filterPredicate to search all columns

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Mat Table that uses a filter bar. I previously had the not been using a filterPredicate function and the table would filter based on all columns and data from the Datasource.

I have since added this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string): boolean => {
    if (this.columnSearch === "(All)") {
      return;
    }
    if (!data[this.columnSearch]) {
      data[this.columnSearch] = "";
    }
    return data[this.columnSearch]
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(filter);
  };
}
```

The `this.columnSearch` variable is 2 way bound to my select control. This control defines which column is currently being filtered. I want the `"(All)"` selection to filter from all columns. I need a way to disable the filterPredicate when All columns is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Datasource FilterPredicate Expression

```
// Filter Predicate Expression to perform Multiple KeyWord Search
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = ((data: DeviceInventory, filter) => {
      const a = !filter.uniqueNumber || data.uniqueNumber.trim().toLowerCase().includes(filter.uniqueNumber);
      const b = !filter.model || data.modelCode==filter.model;
      const c = !filter.modelType || data.modelType == filter.modelType;
      const d = !filter.serialNumber || data.serialNumber.trim().toLowerCase().includes(filter.serialNumber);
      return a && b && c && d;
    }) as (DeviceInventory, string) => boolean;


// Filter Controls FormValue change event
this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.dataSource.filter = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I can up with. Looping through the all object keys and returning true or false using includes()

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string): boolean => {

  // Check if "All Columns" is selected.
  // Loop through table object keys and check if the filter matches any. 
  if (this.columnSearch === "(All Columns)") {
    for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(data).length; index++) {
      const key = Object.keys(data)[index];
      if (!data[key]) {
        data[key] = "";
      }
      if (
        data[key]
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(filter)
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  if (!data[this.columnSearch]) {
    data[this.columnSearch] = "";
  }

  return data[this.columnSearch]
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(filter);
};
```